# USBProber replacement in El Capitan

Tags: macos, usb, developer-tools

There used to be a useful utility called USBProber for OS X, but I can no longer locate it. I am assuming it has been replaced by another utility, but I am not sure what Apple replaced it with or where I can find it.

The last time USBProber worked was with OS X 10.9 and I need the replacement that will work with 10.11 (El Capitan).

USBProber required a kernel extension to function correctly and as the README stated:

> IMPORTANT: If the incorrect version of the IOUSBFamily kernel
>   extension is installed, the system may panic on startup. Verify that
>   you are installing this release of the IOUSBFamily to the matching
>   version of OS X.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/781982/how-can-i-install-usb-prober-from-the-developer-sdk-on-mac-os-x) it is not a standard part of Xcode:

> Search for iOUSBFamily and download the latest version on the
>   [developer page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)
>
> Installing the package is not recommended as it will overwrite your
>   installed kernel extension, and can cause kernel panics at startup if
>   the version downloaded does not match the OS.

Comment: Updated my question to make it clear that I am looking for a replacement that will work with 10.11 (El Capitan)